# Get the last 100 rows from cassandra table

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax, cql

I have a table in cassandra now i cannot select the last 200 rows in the table.
The clustering order by clause was supposed to enforce sorting on disk.

```
CREATE TABLE t1(id int , 
event text, 
receivetime timestamp ,
PRIMARY KEY (event, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id DESC)
;
```

The output is unsorted by id:

```
event   | id | receivetime
---------+----+---------------------------------
  event1 |  1 | 2021-07-12 08:11:57.702000+0000
  event7 |  7 | 2021-05-22 05:30:00.000000+0000
  event5 |  5 | 2021-05-25 05:30:00.000000+0000
  event9 |  9 | 2021-05-22 05:30:00.000000+0000
  event2 |  2 | 2021-05-21 05:30:00.000000+0000
 event10 | 10 | 2021-05-23 05:30:00.000000+0000
  event4 |  4 | 2021-05-24 05:30:00.000000+0000
  event6 |  6 | 2021-05-27 05:30:00.000000+0000
  event3 |  3 | 2021-05-22 05:30:00.000000+0000
  event8 |  8 | 2021-05-21 05:30:00.000000+0000
```

How do I overcome this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ordering for a clustering order, is the order within a single partition key value, e.g. all of the rows for event1 would be in order for event1. It is not a global ordering.

From your results we can see you are selecting multiple partitions - which is why you are not seeing an order you expect.

Comment: The keyspace in which this table is created as a replication factor of 1. How do I get the global ordering of the table?

Comment: You would need to select the data out via spark and sort externally, even with an RF of 1, the data is distributed.

Answer (score 1):

The same question was asked on https://community.datastax.com/questions/11983/ so I'm re-posting my answer here.

The rows within a partition are sorted based on the order of the clustering column, not the partition key.

In your case, the table's primary key is defined as:

```
    PRIMARY KEY (event, id)
```

This means that each partition key can have one or more rows, with each row identified by the id column. Since there is only one row in each partition, the sorting order is not evident. But if you had multiple rows in each partition, you'd be able to see that they would be sorted. For example:

```
 event   | id | receivetime
---------+----+---------------------------------
  event1 |  7 | 2021-05-22 05:30:00.000000+0000
  event1 |  5 | 2021-05-25 05:30:00.000000+0000
  event1 |  1 | 2021-07-12 08:11:57.702000+0000
```

In the example above, the partition `event1` has 3 rows sorted by the ID column in reverse order.

In addition, running unbounded queries (no `WHERE` clause filter) is an anti-pattern in Cassandra because it requires a full table scan. If you consider a cluster which has 500 nodes, an unbounded query has to request all the partitions (records) from all 500 nodes to return the result. It will not perform well and does not scale. Cheers!